# How to select frame if there are multiple frames on a webpage and get content of that frame?

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the content of the email from site name "yopmail.com" which is having multiple frames. I need to switch to the frame name = 'ifmail' and want to getText from email body.

Please see screenshot for yopmail:

[image]

Anyone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use the below code to get the text of email body:

```
 Thread.sleep(4000);
 driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");

List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#mailmillieu>div>div[dir='ltr']>div"));

for(WebElement element: elems){

    if(!element.getText().equals("")){
        System.out.println("body is "+element.getText());
    }

}
```

i use "" as there are some br and new line in my body. But it will show all the text of ur body.

Comment: Thanks noor, this one works for me. I am able to get text from Email body by switching to frame

Answer (score 0):

You can give the name as parameter to the `switch` command

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");
```

Comment: I already tried with below two options but none are working :

driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");
AND
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@id='ifmail'")));

Comment: Now able to switch to the frame and able to extract text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please handle iframe like below

1. driver.switchTo().frame(int arg0); // Select a frame by its (zero-based) index. That is, if a page has multiple frames (more than 1), the first frame would be at index "0", the second at index "1" and so on.

   `List<WebElement> iframeElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));`

   ```
   System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());
   ```
2. driver.switchTo().frame(String arg0); // Below is the example code snippet using frame
   a.Name.
   b.Id.
   c.WebElement

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
   System.out.println("Navigated to frame with name " + frame);
   ```
3. Switching back to Main page from Frame

   ```
   driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
   ```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to frame by name, id, webelement , index

Here the HTML of frame:-

```
<iframe class="whc" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" id="ifmail" name="ifmail" src=""></iframe>
```

You id and name have the same name so you can switch it as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ifmail");
```

OR

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='ifmail']")));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below, hope it helps:

//Switch to Main page first

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//Switch to the desired frame

driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

// perform steps you want to do

//and then Switching to Main page again

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();